# Sort and dedupe java collections

Tags: java

I want to achieve the following, I have a collection of dates in a list form which I want deduped and sorted. I'm using collections.sort to sort the list in ascending date order and then using a treeSet to copy and dedupe elements from the list. This is a 2 shot approach ? Is there a faster, 1 step approach ?

```
EDIT:: 

Metadata
{
 String name;
 Date sourceDate;
}
```

Basically I want to order Metadata object based on the sourceDate and dedupe it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the `Collections#sort` step: `TreeSet` will remove duplicates and sort the entries. So basically it is a one line operation:

```
Set<Date> sortedWithoutDupes = new TreeSet<Date> (yourList);
```

If the Date is a field in your object, you can either:

- have your object implement Comparable and compare objects based on their date
- or pass a `Comparator<YourObject>` as an argument to the TreeSet constructor, that sorts your objects by date

In both cases, you don't need to pre-sort your list.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

TreeSet uses `compareTo` to compare keys. So if 2 keys have the same date but different names, you should make sure that your compare or compareTo method returns a non-0 value, otherwise the 2 objects will be considered equal and only one will be inserted.

**EDIT**

The code could look like this (not tested + you should handle nulls):

```
Comparator<Metadata> comparator = new Comparator<Metadata>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Metadata o1, Metadata o2) {
        if (o1.sourceDate.equals(o2.sourceDate)) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        } else {
            return o1.sourceDate.compareTo(o2.sourceDate);
        }
    }
};

Set<Metadata> sortedWithoutDupes = new TreeSet<Metadata> (comparator);
sortedWithoutDupes.addAll(yourList);
```

Comment: But what if date is a field in my object ? Then can treeset order it in ascending order of dates ?

Comment: @Phoenix That is slightly different but it still works - see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

TreeSet will automatically sort its elements, so you shouldn't need to sort the list before adding to the set.

Comment: But the treeset constructor allows for only one thing, either dedupe or order and not both. How can I do that in one step as I need to copy the elements from an existing list ?

Comment: Sets always dedupe, it's impossible for them to contain duplicates - at least that's a requirement of the interface.  They'll do that automatically with any constructor or any add operation.