# How to remove duplicates based on id from the bean using java?

Tags: java

I have a list of bean, how to remove duplicates based on id from the bean
Give me how to remove it in code wise?

```
List<Tasks>task =

[
    {
    "title": "Title1",
    "description": "Description1",
    "id": "123456"

    },
    {
    "title": "Title2",
    "description": "Description2",
    "id": "123456"

    },
    {
    "title": "Title3",
    "description": "Description3",
    "id": "123456"

    },
    {
    "title": "Title4",
    "description": "Description4",
    "id": "654321"

    }
]
```

My expected output is anyone of the list from id=123456 and 654321

```
[

    {
    "title": "Title2",
    "description": "Description2",
    "id": "123456"

    },
    {
    "title": "Title4",
    "description": "Description4",
    "id": "654321"

    }
]
```

Comment: Populate a Map<String, Task> where the key is the ID. Then get the values of the Map.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491408/sort-and-dedupe-java-collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, Task> map = new HashMap<>():
tasks.forEach(t -> map.put(t.getId(), t);
Collection<Task> withoutDuplicates = map.values();
```

Comment: i tried your answer but it shows error in The type Collections is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Tasks>

Comment: It's a typo. The type is Collection, not Collections. But you really need to understand these 3 lines of code. Not copy and paste them. Read the javadoc of Map, and Map.values(), and Map.put(), to understand.

Comment: how to return as list means Colllection object conatins withoutDuplicates how this data convert to List<Tasks>

Comment: `return new ArrayList<>(withoutDuplicates);`

Answer (score -2):

You can add equals method in your bean Class.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(id.equals((YourBeanClass)obj).id)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

where id is Bean object Id.
And for storing `ArrayList` data use `LinkedHashSet` which will avoid duplicates.Or if you are using `ArrayList` you can use contains method to check if Bean object already exist before adding.

Comment: is it posiible to remove duplicates in code wise without any amodification in bean class

Comment: No i guess, you need override equals() function as all Structures internally use equals function to compare the Object. You may use one more line of code LinkedHashSet<Task> tasklist = new LinkedHashSet(yourtasklist);

Comment: Again see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491408/sort-and-dedupe-java-collections the accepted answer shows you how to dedupe using a custom comparator without rewriting your class.

Comment: In that case He need to implement  Comparable interface and need to implement CompareTo function in Bean class. plus extra Comparator object. instead LinkedHashSet (Or any other Structure that can handle duplicates) can handle it by itself

Comment: @Swapnil you're talking nonsense. If you use a Comparator, you don't need the class to implement Comparable. And the linked answer does use a data structure handing duplicates: a TreeSet. That said, using a HashMap is way easier. See my answer. Also, your eqals()method doesn't respect the contract of equals(), and using a LinkedHashSet with what you suggest would fail, since you didn't override hashCode.